# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am learning React and creating a simple calculator. All HTML is created within React. I am getting a TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null. The HTML is rendered before the other functions so I am unsure why I am getting the error message.
The HTML:

```
function App() {
    return (
    <div className="App">

        <label>Number 1: </label>
        <input type="text" id="x"></input>

        <br></br>

        <label>Number 2: </label>
        <input type="text" id="y"></input>

        <br></br>

        <button onClick={add()}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={subtract()}>Subtract</button>

        <br></br>
        <output id="out"></output>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is where I am getting the error (at the .innerHTML):

```
function add() {
    var x = document.getElementById('x').innerHTML
    var y = document.getElementById('y').innerHTML
    var z = x + y
    document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = z
}
```

Comment: where did you put add function ?

Comment: Obviously the HTML isn't rendered before that Javascript is run, that's why it's null when you try to get the element. Where and how are you including/running your React code and that vanilla JS code?

Comment: The add() function is directly after the App() function

Comment: you should be using raw dom APIs in react.

Comment: @RyanTremblay yes but where are they *executed*. They're defined one after the other, ok fine, but how are you running them, and how are you including the scripts into your application

Comment: Looking at the code you also have some syntax issues, like `onClick={add()}` means the function executes straight away, you should be passing in the function itself: `onClick={add}`. But all that aside, why are you mixing React and vanilla JS? DO the stuff you're doing inside add/subtract the proper React way, using state and functions defined inside the component

Comment: @Jayce444 Thank you for that I am all set now I am very new to both React and JS and don't know the "proper React way" yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check tutorials on react, this is very basic start to learn code and not full proof but it will explain you how react works.

For react, you don't need to get DOM values, it is react which manages the dom.

Codepen : https://codepen.io/ktdev/pen/rNWwNVJ

```
const App = () => {

    const [number1, setNumber1] = React.useState(0);
    const [number2, setNumber2] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setNumber1(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div className="box">
            <label>Number 1: </label>
            <input
                type="text"
                id="x"
                onChange={(e) => setNumber1(Number(e.target.value))}
            ></input>
            <br />
            <label>Number 2: </label>
            <input
                type="text"
                id="y"
                onChange={(e) => setNumber2(Number(e.target.value))}
            ></input>
            <br />
            {number1} + {number2} = {number1 + number2}
            <br />
            {number1} - {number2} = {number1 + number2}
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```